# how to know smartd test was successfully completed or not

Tags: linux, smart

I am using smartmontools 6 and redhat5.In my smartmontool, smartd dameaon is working fine that means logs at the location 
of `/opt/smarttool/logs` changes at every 30 minute.

logs file name are:

1. `savestatesWDC_WD2500AAKX_221CA1-WD_WMAYUA520570.ata.state`
2. `attributelogWDC_WD2500AAKX_221CA1-WD_WMAYUA520570.ata.csv`
3. `attributelogTRANSCEND-20100412____CF1007B4.ata.csv`

Now I want to execute a test using `smartd` by updating entries in `smartd.conf` file. At many sites I read that logs generates
at the location of `/var/log/messages` when error or failure occurs. But I don't know that error occurred or not while 
executing the test or logs are not generated at the location of `/var/log/messages`.

Is there any way to know test was successfully completed or not because I want to save the status of test that means
completed or not or failure or error.​

Answer (score 1):

You can send yourself mails when smartd scans detect and issue, see e.g. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools#Actions_in_case_of_trouble or https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/S.M.A.R.T.#Email_potential_problems 
on how to do that. For some events or if you want to set custom thresholds you might need to [adjust the `smart.conf` file](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/S.M.A.R.T.#Alert_on_temperature_changes)

Or you can configure syslog so that smart errors/critical issues (or anything else that might come up during a smartd-triggered check) get a separate logfile or a separate syslog facility, which you can easily monitor as you like. Check the **NOTES** section at the bottom of the [smart man page](https://www.smartmontools.org/browser/trunk/smartmontools/smartd.8.in) for details on the required changes to syslog configuration. For more details on syslog configuration with smartd, check http://blog.stalkr.net/2009/10/logging-smartd-messages-with-rsyslog.html

If you want to check the logs against the current status of the drives, run some manually triggered short tests with `smartctl` and compare that to what you see in the logs.

Hope this answers your question, if not please specify what is missing.